# Insert a datatable directly under my chart in Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-charts

How do I create a data table directly under my chart on Google spreadsheets? I want to achieve something similar to the figure below. In MS Excel it is called datatable and it is inserted by a click of a button.

[image: example chart]

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, at this time charts in Google Sheets don't include a datatable option.

**References**
[Create a chart or graph - Docs Editors Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/63728?hl=en)
[Editing and formatting your chart - Docs Editors Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/63824?rd=1)